# Reattach a removed event handler doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the click of an element when it is clicked (I'm using `off()` for this), and want to reattach the click when the element isn't clicked ('actived'). To indicate it is not clicked, I'm using a class named 'disabled'.

**But when I remove, I cant add it again.** It just doesn't attach the event again!

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
$('.my-element').on('click', function() {
  $('.my-element').off('click');
});

var disabled = setInterval(function() {
 if($('.my-element').hasClass('not-clicked')) {
    $('.my-element').on();
  }
}, 1000);
```

I'm using setInterval() to watch whether the element isn't clicked. If it isn't, it can be using on() again.

I have even tried to remove the event handler in the browser console:

```
$('.my-element').off();
```

But when I try to reattach the event handler...

```
$('.my-element').on();
```

It doesn't work, and will not repeat the behavior.

Comment: Because you don't rebind anything...calling `.on` doesn't remember the events.

Comment: Using `setInterval` here is a bad idea.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: @tymeJV, theres a function attacted to click: the one I removed with off(). How can i get the function and turn it on again?

Comment: @Vohuman  using `setInterval` is _almost always_ a bad idea...

Comment: So could you guys suggest something to watch whether the element gets a class?

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.on()` doesn't remember removed events, but you can save the current events before removing them with:

```
var handlers;
$('.my-element').on('click', function() {
    handlers = $.extend(true, {}, $._data( this, "events" ));
    $('.my-element').off('click');
});
```

and then attach with:

```
$(".my-element").on("click", handlers.click[0].handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `on` and `off` without any parameters has no effect. Ideally you should pass the name of the event and it's handler to those methods.

```
var handler = function() {
   // ...
}
$('.my-element').on('click.namespace', handler);
// ...
$('.my-element').off('click.namespace', handler);
```

If the handler should be called only once you could also consider using the `one` method. Also using `setIntevarl` here is a bad idea. You should bind the handler right after adding the class. In this case I'd suggest using event delegation technique:

```
$('#aStaticParent').on('click', '.my-element.not-clicked', function() {
    // the handler is called only if the element has `not-clicked` className
    $(this).removeClass('not-clicked');
});
```